# create an Android app from a Flash .swf file

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am newbie in Android Development, I have some SWF file which which is developed using some Flash Action Script.

Now I have develop a Android Application using those flash files.

I have Google a lot and found we can do with Adobe Air.

Could any body help me to develop this .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-2ae4ef8612b2d078909-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple just use flash builder a plugin of eclipse and replace the swf that has been 
generated with your own swf and you are good to do.
It can be done in the application xml look for .swf

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many workflows for creating native apps using the AIR SDK.

If you prefer IDEs, you can use the free [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) or [Adobe's Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html).

If you are more a designer, you can use [Adobe Flash CC](https://creative.adobe.com/products/flash).

If you like using the command line, you can download the free [AIR SDK directly](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html).  I published [a blogpost](http://jcward.com/Adobe+AIR+Mobile+Development+On+Linux) about this flow in a Linux development environment, and a [barebones AIR project on github](https://github.com/jcward/BaseAIRAppLinux).

That should get you started.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the .fla , you can go to "File" -> "Publish Settings" and configure how you want to be made your apk, but you will have to sign it as well.

If this is Flex ( Flash Builder ) , you have to go to export and change the settings.

If you don't have the source code, it is still possible to export it to apk, but will be a lot more hassle.